# how to resolve TypeError: language_model_learner() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arch' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

Hi I am struck here please help me with this issue

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: language_model_learner() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arch'
```

I am following this tutorial :- https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/11/tutorial-text-classification-ulmfit-fastai-library/

[image]

Comment: may be you need to see how this function works

Comment: Looks like the function call is missing 1 required positional argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://docs.fast.ai/text.learner.html#language_model_learner

You need to define architecture, like this:

```
language_model_learner(data, AWD_LSTM, drop_mult=0.5)
```